# FLASH PROFESSIONAL CS6 using ACTIONSCRIPT 3

Tags: flash-cs6

```
var theXML:XML = new XML();

theXML.ignoreWhite = true;

theXML.onLoad = function()
{

    var nodes = this.firstChild.childNodes;

    for(i = 0; i < nodes.length;  i++)
    {
        theList.addItem(nodes[i].firstChild.nodeValue, i);
    }
};

theXML.load("http://localhost/xampp/phpflash/account.php");
```

---

These are the errors:

> -1120: Access of undefined property i.
>
> -1137: Incorrect number of arguments. Expected no more than 1.

I'm so newbie on this subject. Please help me with your kind and consideration.

Answer (score 0):

1: you should declare i.
2: addItem function should only have one argument.

```
var theXML:XML = new XML();

theXML.ignoreWhite = true;

theXML.onLoad = function()
{

    var nodes = this.firstChild.childNodes;

    for(var i:int = 0; i < nodes.length;  i++)
    {
        theList.addItem(nodes[i].firstChild.nodeValue);
    }
};

theXML.load("http://localhost/xampp/phpflash/account.php");
```